# Bootstrap sectioned progress bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to bootstrap. I need to create a sectioned progress bar (attached image) with each section having label above it. I have tried with multiple div with column classes but not able to achieve the exact requirement.

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you have so far?

Comment: Refer to my answer edits, i hope it works as you need in your answer, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ***Bootstrap Stacked Progress Bars***, *For example:*

*Create a stacked progress bar by placing multiple bars into the same `<div class="progress">`*

```
<div class="progress">

    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:40%"> Free Space</div>

    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" style="width:10%">Warning</div>

    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width:20%">Danger</div>

</div>
```

***See w3schools.com [DEMO](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_progressbar6&stacked=h)***

---

***See this example:*** *I hope it works as you need, Thanks.*

```css
.progress-bar-success{
  border:solid 1px;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<br /><br />
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:20%">Label 1</div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:20%">Label 2</div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:20%">Label 3</div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:20%">Label 4</div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:20%">Label 5</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```